# Changing image size in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, resampling

I did interpolation operation on temperature and precipitation data.

Output image size is 3300 (col) and 2550 (row). I have some NDVI images with size of 15456 (col) and 5074 (row). Generally, I want the interpolated images to be the same size with NDVI images.

After doing interpolation, I wanted to do resampling on temp/prec images in order to not loss any information on image (3300: 2550 to 15456:5074 size). But resampling method only works on raster image.

Is there any tool or procedure in ArcGIS Desktop to set a image size when I'm interpolating temperature and precipitation data?

Do you have any suggestion to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

When you run geoprocessing operations in ArcMap (e.g. tools from the ArcToolbox pane) they conform to two sets of parameters. First are the parameters in the window itself, e.g. input file, output file path, etc. Second are the parameters in the Environment Settings window (see below).

[image: Interpolation window]

These Environment Settings let you fine-tune your geoprocessing operations in myriad ways. In your case, you want the interpolation image to have the same extent, same pixel size, and same pixel registration (i.e. the corners of the pixels are in the exact same spot). To do this, choose your NDVI data files for the "[Extent](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Output_Extent/001w00000009000000/)" and "[Snap Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Snap_Raster/001w0000000m000000/)" parameters under the "Processing Extent" heading (see below). By doing this, the output raster from the interpolation will have the same processing extent and pixel registration as the NDVI data.

[image: Environments settings window]

If you want Environment settings to persist across multiple geoprocessing operations, you can set environments for the entire Map Document by opening the Environments window under the "Geoprocessing" menu in ArcMap (see below).

[image: Environments...]

Comment: (+1) This clearly illustrated reply resolves a *lot* of related raster-processing questions in ArcGIS.

Comment: Hello everyone?